# Edit strapi relations in place

Tags: strapi

Does the Strapi admin interface support editing relations in-place, i.e. creating content and its related content at the same time? Or is there a plugin supporting this?

I think Contentful has support for this.

Comment: Not that I aware of. You have to do relations in advance, but I’m guessing it’s on their todo list https://feedback.strapi.io/customization/p/create-an-entry-from-a-relational-field